# Call to a member function notify() on null, Laravel echo

Tags: laravel-5, vue.js

Hola a todos nuevamente

Estoy trabajando con pusher para hacer las notificaciones a usuarios al momento de ingresar un registro de ordenIngreso. Esto se guarda en mi tabla entry_orders, pero no me está guardando la notificación en la base de datos.

EntryOrderController.php

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $rules = [
            'orderNumber' => 'required|min:9|unique:entry_orders',
            'plate' => 'required|min:6',
            'chasis' => 'required|min:17'
        ];
        $this->validate($request, $rules);

        $campos = $request->all();
        $entry = EntryOrder::create($campos);
        return response()->json(['data' => $entry], 201);

        $fechaActual = date('Y-m-d');
        $numOrders = DB::table('entry_orders')->whereDate('created_at',$fechaActual)->count();

        $arregloDatos = [
            'orders' => [
                'numero' => $numOrders,
                'msj' => 'Ingreso Vehículo'
            ]
        ];
        $allUsers = User::all();
        foreach ($allUsers as $notificar) {
            User::findOrFail($notificar->id)->notify(new NotifyAdmin($arregloDatos));
        }

    }
```

En esta línea no me está reconociendo el metodo notify (creo que acá está el error)

```
User::findOrFail($notificar->id)->notify(new NotifyAdmin($arregloDatos));
```

Espero me puedan iluminar un poco en que me estoy equivocando.
Gracias amigos.